# iOS code: Fails on other machines, but not mine with [NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil'

Tags: ios, file-io, nsfilemanager

I'm developing with a team, using macs that were all imaged exactly the same. Using the machine on which I wrote the code, I can programmatically create and then write to a pList file. But when I use my home machine (same image) or when my teammates test the code on their machines, we crash with a **[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path is nil'** error. In debugging, the filepath is valid. The bundle, however, in:

```
 NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Family" ofType:@"plist"];
    [pListfileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: pListpath error:&error];
```

is nil. We are using git to version control our code. We have been keeping .DS_Store and /userdata/ files out of the repo, unless I've missed something. What is going on? Here is the code, reproduced almost verbatim from [here](http://www.leesilver.net/1/post/2011/8/storing-data-locally-on-plists-in-ios.html):

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *pListpaths =NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,  YES);

NSString *pListdocumentsDirectory = [pListpaths objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pListpath = [pListdocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Family.plist"];
NSFileManager *pListfileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//Create a plist if it doesn't alread exist
if (![pListfileMgr fileExistsAtPath: pListpath])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Family" ofType:@"plist"];
    [pListfileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: pListpath error:&error];
}

NSMutableDictionary *thePList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: pListpath];

[thePList setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", numberOfPeopleInFamilyOfOrigin] forKey:@"famSize"];
[thePList writeToFile: pListpath atomically: YES];
```

Comment: Still seeking an answer. I just want to stress that we want to be able to CREATE this plist file if it does not already exist. It's primarily for writing TO, not creating by hand to read in static values to fill a table or some other fields. If I have understood, @Olaf below says I should make sure the file resource is copying over to my teammates' bundles. This is not my goal (unless I am wrong and don't know what I'm talking about).

Comment: UPDATE: I deleted the app from MY simulator and ran a new build. Now the project on MY machine is throwing the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting the intent of the code you've listed above.

The following block is checking for the existence of a file located at path `pListpath`.  If a file does not exist at `pListpath`, it copies a file from *within* your bundle to `pListpath`.

```
//Create a plist if it doesn't alread exist
if (![pListfileMgr fileExistsAtPath: pListpath])
{
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Family" ofType:@"plist"];
    [pListfileMgr copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: pListpath error:&error];
}
```

That is to say, you must ship a file called `Family.plist` within your bundle, the intent being that this file would act as a *default* plist if the a plist does not already exist at path `pListpath`.

Comment: This is exactly what confused me and caused different behaviour on other machines. I thought the code meant "if the file doesn't exist in the bundle, create it in the bundle". I thought the data would be written to the bundle file. When I saw it had created and written to a local directory, I thought "Neat, I don't need that file in my app anymore; it doesn't do anything" and promptly deleted it and pushed up my changes. Things kept running fine for me, since my file existed at pListpath. But my teammates didn't have a file there, nor did they have a file in their bundle, so it crashed.

Comment: I also had a terminology problem: a _bundle_ is something 'bundled' with your app during a build. So, "is it in your bundle?" means, "is it amongst the files that make up your app?" and even more literally in my case "can you see it amongst the files in your xCode file navigator?" Maybe too obvious, but hopefully this helps others.

Answer (score 0):

Does `Family.plist` exist inside your App bundle?

Xcode has a habit of not updating changed(added) resources into the bundle. The usual remedy is to delete the app off the simulator/device and to install new.

If your teammates have an older installation on their simulator, in other words, a fresh build but the time of the first install is before the time that `Family.plist` was added to the project, then this could be it.

Your teammate can verify the existence of the `Family.plist` by navigating (in Finder) to `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`, then do a `Show Package Contents` of `yourAppName.app`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a couple things in this situation:

Printing out the value of `pListpath` then checking to see if it exists on the local file system or if the directory path is misconstructed.

If the problem doesn't exist in the path construction, I would explicitly create `Family.plist` and make sure you include it is included under `Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources`.

Also, when working in a shared environment, often cruft builds up and clearing my project's Derived Data usually helps to solve some issues. You can do this by:
1) Opening the organizer.
2) Navigating to the projects tab.
3) Find and select your project on the left.
4) Delete derived data.